# Floating Point Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

How this loop is performing and why it doesn't print 2.399999999999999

```
i = 1.2

while i < 2.4:
    print(i)
    i += 0.2
```

Also when I tried :

```
2.39999999999999999 < 2.4
```

I got `False`

But when I tried :

```
2.399999999999999 < 2.4
```

I got `True`

Can anyone explain why it is so ?

Comment: Do you understanding floating point imprecision? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi @Chris_Rands Can you spread some light or refer me any documentation for the same, I am still not clear why 2.39999999999999999 < 2.4 is False and 2.399999999999999 < 2.4 is True.

Comment: Your first example `2.39999999999999999 < 2.4` is equivalent to `2.4 < 2.4` because of the limited precision of floating point.

Comment: See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5987)

Comment: To see what I'm talking about, try `2.39999999999999999 == 2.4`.

Comment: @MarkRansom it is coming True

Answer (score 1):

This is because computer architecture either rounds the number or truncate the number. In this scenario, if we see architecture level either considering the number equals to 2.4 or greater than just by Machine epsilon.

It is good to have a look at the concept of Machine Epsilon.

Comment: So 2.39999999999999999 < 2.4 is False and 2.399999999999999 < 2.4 is True due to Machine Epsilon ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi it's because the difference between 2.39999999999999999 and 2.4 is less than half of epsilon*2.4.